# Create learning cards

Tags: templates

Is there a document class available that allows for the creation of learning cards?

I thought of an environment that allows me to define a question and the according solution. The final document has for example 6 questions on every even page and the according 6 answers on every odd page -> I can simply cut out the learning cards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about the flashcards class on CTAN? Looks like they already have layouts for one of the printable Avery index card templates, but you could just cut along the same dimensions yourself.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flashcards/

Answer (score 10):

Note that [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) and [Mnemosyne](http://www.mnemosyne-proj.org/) are advanced flashcard programs (they learn what you know and don't know) that support LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this class called "[kartei](http://www.rbergmann.info/projekte/kartei.html)". Unfortunately the description is in German but supports quite some formats. The Package itself can be downloaded [here](http://www.rbergmann.info/projekte/kartei/Kartei.1.8b.zip).